# I cannot get the srt dataframe to fill in my code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, process

I cannot get this code to output or fill the dataframe correctly

It seems that the issue lies within the code where the results are being converted to a DataFrame

here is what the output should look like:

[working output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVyYd.png)

This is what the output looks like:

```
SRT Results:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Process, Arrival Time, Service Time, Start Time, Finish Time, Wait Time, Turnaround Time]
Index: []
SRT Gantt Chart:
(empty line here)
```

Here is the srt code :

```
def SRT(processes):
    process_info = [None] * len(processes)
    remaining_time = [p[2] for p in processes]
    current_time = 0

    while True:
        idx = -1
        min_remaining_time = float('inf')
        
        for i, process in enumerate(processes):
            if process[1] <= current_time and remaining_time[i] < min_remaining_time and remaining_time[i] > 0:
                idx = i
                min_remaining_time = remaining_time[i]
                
        if idx == -1:
            if all(rt == 0 for rt in remaining_time):
                break
            else:
                current_time += 1
                continue

        remaining_time[idx] -= 1

        if process_info[idx] is None:
            start_time = current_time
            process_info[idx] = [processes[idx][0], processes[idx][1], processes[idx][2], start_time]

        if remaining_time[idx] == 0:
            finish_time = current_time + 1
            wait_time = process_info[idx][3] - processes[idx][1]
            turnaround_time = finish_time - processes[idx][1]
            process_info[idx] += [finish_time, wait_time, turnaround_time]

        current_time += 1

    return process_info
```

Here is the gantt chart snippet

```
def visualize_gantt_chart(process_info, algorithm):
    process_info.sort(key=lambda x: x[3]) # Sort by start time
    gantt_chart = ""

    for process in process_info:
        gantt_chart += " " * (process[3] - len(gantt_chart))
        gantt_chart += str(process[0]) * (process[4] - process[3])

    print(f"{algorithm} Gantt Chart:")
    print(gantt_chart)

processes = [
    [1, 0, 3],
    [2, 2, 6],
    [3, 4, 4],
    [4, 6, 5],
    [5, 8, 2]
]
```

here is how i am outputting the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(srt_info, columns=['Process', 'Arrival Time', 'Service Time', 'Start Time', 'Finish Time', 'Wait Time', 'Turnaround Time'])
print("\nSRT Results:")
print(df)
```

```
visualize_gantt_chart(srt_info, "SRT")
```